# Partition List by indices

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So there is a list `List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and a list of indices `Indices = [1, 2, 4]`.

I want to partition the list into two lists: one containing the elements at the `Indices` (`['b', 'c', 'e']`) and one containing all other elements (`['a', 'd'`).

For the first list I already have simple solution.

```
In_List = [List[i] for i in Indices]
```

However, for the other list I only have a rather ugly solution

```
Out_List = [List[i] for i in range(len(List)) if i not in Indices]
```

The Solution I have works, ... But it feels like there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

Any Suggestions?

**Edit/Update**

It seems that there are 3 suggestions:

**One Loop over indices:**

```
    In_List = []
    Out_List = []
    for i in range(len(List)):
        if i in Indices:
            In_List.append(List[i])
        else:
            Out_List.append(List[i])
```

**Loop via enumerate:**

```
    In_List = []
    Out_List = []
    for index, value in enumerate(List):
        if index in Indices:
            In_List += [value]
        else:
            Out_List += [value]
```

**Using Numpy:**

```
    Indices = np.array(Indices)
    List = np.array(List)
    In_List = list(List[Indices])
    Out_List = list(np.delete(List, Indices))
```

Thanks to everybody for the suggestion.

I took these three solutions and my initial solution and compared them for differently sized Lists(`range(10, 1000, 10)`) picking one eighth of the elements every time - averaged over 100 repetitions. It seems that list comprehension is slightly faster than the loops, but not significantly. Numpy seems slower for short lists but absolutely crushes the other solutions for larger lists.

**Edit/Update**: made the numpy version also return a list and then updated the graph.

[image]

Comment: `Out_List = [List[i] for i in sorted(set(range(len(List)) - set(Indices))]`

Comment: If you have a working solution and would like to improve it, consider asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not more elgant, but at least you avoid running two for loops (which is quite inefficient if you are dealing with a lot of data).

```
In_List = []
Out_List = []
for i in range(len(List)):
    if i in Indices:
        In_List.append(List[i])
    else:
        Out_List.append(List[i])
```

**Edit:** you can also write the code above in one liner, but it isn't really readable:

```
in_List = []
out_List = []
[in_List.append(List[j]) if j in Indices else out_List.append(List[j]) for j in range(len(List))]
```

If you are ok in using numpy the code will look nicer (though some people may claim using numpy here is using a machine gun to kill a moskito):

```
import numpy as np
Indices = np.array(Indices)
List = np.array(List)
In_List = List[Indices]
Out_List = np.delete(List, Indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

this would also work:

```
List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Indices = [1, 2, 4]

ret = ([], [])
for i, item in enumerate(List):
    ret[i in Indices].append(item)
Out_List, In_List = ret
```

where i use `i in Indices` as index for the nested tuple `ret` and then unpack it in the last line to get `In_List` and `Out_List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result with only one parsing of your `List` using the `enumerate` method:

```py
List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Indices = [1, 2, 4]

In_List = []
Out_List = []
for index, value in enumerate(List):
    if index in Indices:
        In_List += [value]
    else:
        Out_List += [value]
```

It would be even more efficient if your `Indices` variable was a `set` instead of a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use itemgetter from operator module:

```
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

in_indices = [1, 2, 3]
out_indices = set(range(len(my_list))).difference(in_indices)
# also you ca use:
# out_indices = [0, 4]

in_list = list(itemgetter(*in_indices)(my_list ))
out_list = list(itemgetter(*out_indices)(my_list ))

print(in_list)
print(out_list)
```

output:

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy boolean mask (with [np.in1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)):

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
indices = np.array([1, 2, 4])
m = np.in1d(range(lst.size), indices)
in_list, out_list = lst[m], lst[~m]    # ['b' 'c' 'e'] ['a' 'd']
```